# Opening page in new tabs

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

I want to open new tab on `<a href="">` and want to close current page using JavaScript.

Is this achievable?

here is my code

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('test_2.php', '_blank');window.close();">click here</a>
```

New tab is opening properly but opener window is not getting closed.

Comment: What if the client browser doesn't support tabs?

Comment: You can't close a window you did'nt open. Javascript will let you close any window opened by javascript, but windows opened by the user in their browser is not yours to close.

Comment: Wait. You want to open a new tab, and close the current one? Isn't that just going to a new page?

Comment: It is going to new page but without back button in browser. Basically i want confirmation on browsers back button, i did it for browsers on machines using window.onunload function, but it is not working on iPad browsers, so i decided to open page in new tab itself to avoid back buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Html:

```
<a href='javascript:closeAndOpen("url");'> close this one and open new tab </a>
```

JS:

```
function closeAndOpen(url){
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    window.close();
}
```

Comment: Here is my code <a href="#" onclick="window.open('test_2.php', '_blank');window.close();">click here</a>. New tab is opening properly but existing window is getting closed

Comment: And that's not what you asked?

Comment: It is not working. New tab is opening properly but existing window is getting closed

Comment: I thought that you wanted to open new tab and close current

Comment: @FlorianMargaine It works fine. Where and how have you tested?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986347/opening-page-in-new-tabs/13986361#comment19301933_13986347

Comment: @FlorianMargaine it will not work in jsfiddle, because code there is in iframe. try pasting code in simple html document and then open it

Comment: @FlorianMargaine http://jsfiddle.net/xbuaT/ opens new tab but does not close current, that's because of iframe

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21504/discussion-between-karaxuna-and-florian-margaine)

Comment: Basically i want confirmation on browsers back button, i did it for browsers on machines using window.onunload function, but it is not working on iPad browsers, so i decided to open page in new tab itself to avoid back buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript `window.close()` to close the current tab, and `window.open()` to open a new one.

Comment: I didn't provide a coded answer, I provided the functions needed that the OP failed to provide upon posting. They work, just obviously not as they posted

Comment: No. As said by adeneo, you can't close a window you didn't open.

Comment: Didn't know that last part, wasn't here to see it. Thanks though, that's interesting

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to open a page in a new tab, and close the current? Isn't it the same as staying in the same tab and going to the new page?

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href = 'test_2.php';">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `window.close();` to close a window which was not opened by you with a `javascript`.
One solution is to use `window.location.href = 'test_2.php';` which load your second page over the current page in same tab.
However if you want to stick to your idea of "**open new tab and close current page**" you need to do something like this.

```
onclick="window.open('test_2.php', '_blank');window.open(window.location, '_self').close();"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use window.unload

```
window.onunload=function(){
    window.close();
};
```